# Peace Lily rotting

Tags: leaves, watering, rot, peace-lily

I bought this Peace Lily a month ago and seems not going very well. As you can see, leaves are turning black, even the new leaves. Also, I have to remove one part as it was rotten at the base.

I am watering the plant once a week with bottled water. The plant is not next to a window with direct light or any form of heat. I am not using any fertiliser. I am also dealing with gnats.

It is the second time that this happening with only this type of plant, bought from the same online store. Can be this the problem, poor quality of plants or it is just me?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have fungus gnats, that is an indicator that the soil in the pot has been or is too wet. It may be the plant already had this problem when you bought it, that's hard to know, but do you empty out that outer pot 30 minutes after watering so the plant is not left sitting in water? If not, start doing so. More information on fungus gnats and how to deal with them here 
https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/houseplant-pests/fungus-gnat-control/

Note that bottled water is not always a good thing to use for houseplants - the sodium level can be quite high in some brands, and that is not a good thing for plants. Rain or spring water (preferably collected yourself from a natural source, or a bottled 'natural spring water' with a low sodium level) are best, but tapwater is also fine for plants, so long as it is not artificially softened.

In terms of watering, only water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry the plant is wilting or the soil has shrunk from the sides of pot. Water well, allowing excess to drain away freely from the base, empty the outer pot after 30 minutes, and again 30 minutes later if more has collected.

Comment: I agree with the above and would just like to add, firstly, avoid purchasing more plants from the same supplier and secondly you should remove any dead or damaged material like those badly wilted and discoloured leaves in the pot.